# how do i set xcode build settings to build static lib release and not debug?

Tags: xcode, release

I built a static lib that has Swift and C for a teammate.
It produces:  Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/
and works ok and distributes by TESTFLIGHT.

But teammate wants a release and not debug.

I can't find any settings that do this.

Must distribute to TESTFLIGHT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following configures a Swift & C static lib for release and NOT debug:

Xcode > Product menu > Scheme > Edit Scheme > Build Config.. > select Release